# Null pointer Exception at runtime

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, stack-trace

I am trying to implement the 3d transition effect.Fially I got a `null pointer exception and Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000009e7 (code=-6)`.Below I am posted the stacktrace and point out the error line.

**StackTrace:**

```
12-05 01:51:25.672: W/System.err(2535): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-05 01:51:25.692: W/System.err(2535):     at info.androidhive.tabsswipe.fragment.ActivitySwitcher.apply3DRotation(ActivitySwitcher.java:84)
12-05 01:51:25.692: W/System.err(2535):     at info.androidhive.tabsswipe.fragment.ActivitySwitcher.animationOut(ActivitySwitcher.java:50)
12-05 01:51:25.692: W/System.err(2535):     at info.androidhive.tabsswipe.fragment.MainActivity$SampleWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(StackOverflow.java:74)
12-05 01:51:25.692: W/System.err(2535):     at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:293)
12-05 01:51:25.702: W/System.err(2535):     at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientBridge.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(AwContentsClientBridge.java:96)
12-05 01:51:25.702: W/System.err(2535):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
12-05 01:51:25.702: W/System.err(2535):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
12-05 01:51:25.702: W/System.err(2535):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-05 01:51:25.702: W/System.err(2535):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-05 01:51:25.712: W/System.err(2535):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-05 01:51:25.712: W/System.err(2535):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 01:51:25.712: W/System.err(2535):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-05 01:51:25.712: W/System.err(2535):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-05 01:51:25.712: W/System.err(2535):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-05 01:51:25.712: W/System.err(2535):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-05 01:51:25.772: A/libc(2535): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000009e7 (code=-6), thread 2535 (dhive.tabsswipe)
```

**ActivitySwitcher.java:**

```
public class ActivitySwitcher {

    private final static int DURATION = 300;
    private final static float DEPTH = 400.0f;

    /* ----------------------------------------------- */

    public interface AnimationFinishedListener {
        /**
         * Called when the animation is finished.
         */
        public void onAnimationFinished();
    }

    /* ----------------------------------------------- */

    public static void animationIn(View container, WindowManager windowManager) {
        animationIn(container, windowManager, null);
    }

    public static void animationIn(View container, WindowManager windowManager,
            AnimationFinishedListener listener) {
        apply3DRotation(90, 0, false, container, windowManager, listener);
    }

    public static void animationOut(View container, WindowManager windowManager) {
        animationOut(container, windowManager, null);
    }

    public static void animationOut(View container,
            WindowManager windowManager, AnimationFinishedListener listener) {
        apply3DRotation(0, -90, true, container, windowManager, listener); ----> 50th line
    }

    /* ----------------------------------------------- */

    private static void apply3DRotation(float fromDegree, float toDegree,
            boolean reverse, View container, WindowManager windowManager,
            final AnimationFinishedListener listener) {
        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        final float centerX = display.getWidth() / 2.0f;
        final float centerY = display.getHeight() / 2.0f;

        final Rotate3dAnimation a = new Rotate3dAnimation(fromDegree, toDegree,
                centerX, centerY, DEPTH, reverse);
        a.reset();
        a.setDuration(DURATION);
        a.setFillAfter(true);
        a.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        if (listener != null) {
            a.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    listener.onAnimationFinished();
                }
            });
        }
        container.clearAnimation(); --->84th line error
        container.startAnimation(a);  

    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java:**  **(Edited)**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Fragment implements OnRefreshListener{

  @Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity,
                container, false);

    return rootView;
    }

private class SampleWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d("stac", url);
        if (url.equals("file:///android_asset/first.html")) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.d("stacelse", url);

            final Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Sample1.class);
            i.putExtra("url", url);

            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            ActivitySwitcher.animationOut(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.container),
                    getActivity().getWindowManager(),
                    new ActivitySwitcher.AnimationFinishedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationFinished() {

                            Log.d("Intent Check","First Check"+i);  
                            startActivity(i);

                        }
                    });

            Log.d("Intent Check","Second Check"+i);

            startActivity(i);
            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_out,
                    R.anim.slide_down);
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

I am unable to solve this issue.Anyone can help me with this issue.Thank you.

Comment: For what your id `container` stands??

Comment: The error is on line 84, in the method `apply3DRotation`. If you could highlight that line it will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: @NeilTownsend,is already highlighted this line in code please read questionn again.

Comment: I think your container is null on apply3DRotation.

Comment: @PiyushGupta please Check my edited post.I found out why this null pointer exception occurs.Because In MainActivity,While passing the intent to another activity I used a breakpoint for intent.` Log.d("Intent Check","First Check"+i); .but I didn't seen this intent check` in Logcat.Can you tell me how to pass the contents inside Intent to another activity.It seems ActivitySwitcher class also doesn't pass to another activity with the help of intent.That's why getting null pointer exception in Container

Answer (score 0):

On line 84:

```
`container` must be null
```

So, on line 50:

```
`container` must be null
```

So it looks like `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.container)` in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is returning null. Have you checked its value?